# Adding Source button to ngx-quill in angular 6

Tags: angular, editor, quill

Am using ngx quill for text editor, Now I have to add source button for edit purpose. So I checked this link

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyEjrQ

But here If am adding

```
<div> Hello </div>
```

If am click on the source again I can able to see like

```
<p> Hello <p>
```

So I need to know how do i add source in ngx-quill and output should be same as I typed

Any way to do like that.

Answer (score 1):

Quill uses `<p>` tag for block-level elements. So if you paste `<div></div>`, it will be converted to `<p></p>`. But you can change this default behaviour by using following code with ngx-quill -

```
const parchment = Quill.import('parchment')
const block = parchment.query('block')
block.tagName = 'DIV'
Quill.register(block, true)
```

This will keep all `<div></div>` tags.
Hope this helps:)